# How to use multiple checkboxes to return a single div

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am working on a page with multiple checkboxes, and would like it to return a single div based on any combination of checks. I created a jsfiddle, but even though this is the code on my site that somewhat works, it is not working on jsfiddle:

HTML:

```
<div id="checkboxes">
<input type="checkbox" id="red" name="color">Red
<input type="checkbox" id="blue" name="color">Blue
<input type="checkbox" id="green" name="color">Green
</div>

<br /><br />
<div id="default" style="display:none;">Show this by default</div><br />
<div id="showred" style="display:none;">This is red</div><br />
<div id="showblue" style="display:none;">This is blue</div><br />
<div id="showgreen" style="display:none;">This is green</div><br />
<div id="showpurple" style="display:none;">This is purple</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var r = $('#red');
var b = $('#blue');
var g = $('#green');
var p = r.add(b);

$(r).click(function(){
    if ($(r).is(':not(:checked)')) {
        $('#showred').show();
        $('#showblue').hide();
        $('#showgreen').hide();
        $('#showpurple').hide();
        $('#default').hide();
    } else {
        $('#showred').hide();
        $('#showblue').hide();
        $('#showgreen').hide();
        $('#showpurple').hide();
        $('#default').show();
    }
});

$(b).click(function(){
    if ($(b).is(':not(:checked)')) {
        $('#showred').hide();
        $('#showblue').show();
        $('#showgreen').hide();
        $('#showpurple').hide();
        $('#default').hide();
    } else {
        $('#showred').hide();
        $('#showblue').hide();
        $('#showgreen').hide();
        $('#showpurple').hide();
        $('#default').show();
    }
});

$(g).click(function(){
    if ($(g).is(':not(:checked)')) {
        $('#showred').hide();
        $('#showblue').hide();
        $('#showgreen').show();
        $('#showpurple').hide();
        $('#default').hide();
    } else {
        $('#showred').hide();
        $('#showblue').hide();
        $('#showgreen').hide();
        $('#showpurple').hide();
        $('#default').show();
    }
});

$(p).click(function(){
    if ($(r).is(':not(:checked)') && $(b).is(':not(:checked)')) {
        $('#showred').hide();
        $('#showblue').hide();
        $('#showgreen').hide();
        $('#showpurple').show();
        $('#default').hide();
    } else {
        $('#showred').hide();
        $('#showblue').hide();
        $('#showgreen').hide();
        $('#showpurple').hide();
        $('#default').show();
    }
});        
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/robert316/tu0o1z0s/13/

I would really appreciate any help to get this working correctly, what I would like to happen is:

- User clicks "Red" -> Display red div
- User clicks "Blue" -> Display blue div
- User clicks "Red" and "Blue" -> Only display purple div (no red or blue)

I would also like to fix the behavior that when a user unchecks a box it reverts back to the default div display, ideally, if no boxes are selected it should show default div, and always display the div based on the combination of checkboxes.

Thank you very much for any help with this.

Comment: You need to select "jQuery" as the library. Notice the "$ is not defined" in your console.

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to jsfiddle, and I think I "fixed" it, at least now it's doing something, just wonky checkbox behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/robert316/tu0o1z0s/22/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than creating a color `div` for each color, why not use a single `color-div` and just change its `css` properties / classes? This would eliminate the need for extraneous show-hide / if-else logic when `checkbox` selections are made.

This snippet illustrates how you can "return a div based on any combination of checks" - it relies on css to handle setting the properties of a target `div` but you could very well handle all of this in jQuery as well.

**Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // checkboxes with name 'color', 'color-div', and reset button
  var colors = $("input[name='color']");
  var colorDiv = $("#color-div");
  var reset = $("#reset");



  // bind to 'colors' change event:
  colors.change(function() {

    // empty array to hold the color ids
    var idArr = [];

    // get the checked colors
    var checked = $("input[name='color']:checked");

    // loop and build array
    checked.each(function() {
      idArr.push($(this).prop("id"));
    });

    // function below   
    toggleColors(idArr, colorDiv);

  });



  // reset to defaults
  $("#reset").click(function() {

    // function below
    setDefault(colorDiv);

    // back to hidden
    colorDiv.hide();

    // uncheck the check boxes
    $("input[name='color']:checked").removeAttr("checked");
  });

});



/// function to add color css classes based on checkbox id array
function toggleColors(arr, elem) {

  var arrLen = arr.length;

  // set default if array is empty
  if (arrLen < 1) {
    setDefault(elem);
    return;
  };

  // remove classes, add classes
  elem.removeClass();
  for (i = 0; i < arrLen; i++) {
    elem.addClass(arr[i]);
  }

  // unhide
  elem.show();

}


/// set the color div to "default"
function setDefault(elem) {
  elem.removeClass();
  elem.addClass("default");
}
```

```css
/* 

  using css to handle color and content change! 
  this will prevent you from having to write complicated "if-else"
  jQuery blocks.

*/

#color-div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid 2px #d3d3d3;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.default,
.default:after {
  background-color: #fff;
  content: "Please select a color";
}
.yellow,
.yellow:after {
  background-color: yellow;
  content: "I am Yellow!";
}
.red,
.red:after {
  background-color: red;
  content: "I am Red!";
}
.blue,
.blue:after {
  background-color: blue;
  content: "I am Blue!";
}
.yellow.blue,
.yellow.blue:after {
  background-color: green;
  content: "I am Green!";
}
.yellow.red,
.yellow.red:after {
  background-color: orange;
  content: "I am Orange!";
}
.blue.red,
.blue.red:after {
  background-color: purple;
  content: "I am Purple!";
}
.blue.red.yellow,
.blue.red.yellow:after {
  background-color: brown;
  content: "I am Brown :(";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkboxes">
  <input type="checkbox" id="red" name="color" />
  <label>Red</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="blue" name="color" />
  <label>Blue</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="yellow" name="color" />
  <label>Yellow</label>
</div>

<br />
<br />
<div id="color-div" style="display:none;"></div>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

If css classes isn't your bag, you could essentially handle the same "toggling" through building an equivalent javascript object.

**[Edit - Using a Div for Each Checkbox]**

Since you have control over the properties of the checkboxes, you should use one of these properties to tie to the element being loaded by your query. You should also try to avoid using `id` for more than one element. For example if you have this:

```
<!-- Checkbox -->
<input type="checkbox" id="burgers" name="color" />

<!-- Loaded/hidden content div-->
<div id="burgerDiv" style="display:none;"></div>
```

I would suggest adding to your checkbox either a `data-*` or `value` attribute that ties to the `id` of the hidden div. I'm not sure how well the data attribute is [supported in all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset), however. Example:

```
<!-- Checkbox -->
<input type="checkbox" id="burgers" name="color" value="burgersDiv" data-ref="burgersDiv" />
```

... Then it's pretty easy to hide/show the div:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cktLc87m/40/)

Comment: That is a fantastic answer! Thank you, but in the case of the page I am building I think I have to use a div for each element of the page. I am using the MODx CMS to return snippet queries, basically, I have 3 checkboxes. For example, let's say they are "Burgers", "Fries", and "Beverages". The code looks like: `<div id="burgers" style="display:none;">[[menuQuery? &filter=burgers]] [[menuQuery? &filter=fries]]  etc..` and I would like to return meal options on the menu based on what a user selects. The code you added is really great, and I was wondering how could I adjust to return the divs.

Comment: You have control over the `checkbox` properties though? Like, `id`,`class`, `name`, `data`, etc?

Comment: The div solution worked much better to display the information in my container div, but is there a way to marry the 2 solutions? For example, if a user clicks burger and they click fries, I would like it to display "xx Burger and Fries Combo xx" (or in this case pulling the query of all burger/fries combo menu options from my query snippet) in place of "You picked burgers" and "You picked fries". Thank you so much for all your help on this.

Comment: Why don't you use a combination of the two examples? Example 1) for creating your combos (single div, array to store selected names) and 2) to show/hide the loaded info? You should be able to figure out how to do this on your own at this point ;) - let me know if you get stuck

Comment: I'd say lets start a chat so I could help walk you through (without using comments section here) - but you don't have enough rep yet :P Do you want to learn how to do this? Or do you just want the answer?

Comment: I do wish I had more rep, but I am still learning a lot and hoping to gain as much knowledge as possible and build it up. Part of me would like the basic answer so that I can apply it to my landing pages, but I would really like to learn the process of how it is done. I've just been staring at this issue for a couple days and just feel like I'm going in circles with it.

Comment: Please do not take this sarcastically, thank you so much for letting me figure this out on my own. Your samples really taught me a lot, and I couldn't have solved it without your help. Sincerely, thank you.

Comment: No problem Robert! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone finds this question, here is the final code I used to be able to show single divs from multiple checkbox selections:

**Code Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    // select checkboxes by name
    var packages = $("input[name='cc']"); 
    // set main div id  
    var packageDiv = $("#listings"); 

    // bind to change event
    packages.change(function () {
        
        // empty array
        var idArr = [];
        // get the checked values
        var checked = $("input[name='cc']:checked");
        // loop and build array
        checked.each(function () {
            idArr.push($(this).prop("id"));
        });
        
        // remove whitespace from multiple checkboxes array
        var trimArray = idArr.join("");
        
        toggleShowHide(trimArray, packageDiv);

    });
    
});

function toggleShowHide(arr, elem) {
    
    var arrLen = arr.length;
    
    // clear last selection when unchecking boxes
    $(".hide-me").hide();
    
    // set default if array is empty
    if (arrLen < 1 ){
        setDefault(elem);
    }
    
    // run the show hide based on array of selection
    
    for(i = 0; i < arrLen; i++) {
        // set the name for the selected div
        var temp = "#" + arr + "_div_id";
        
        $(temp).show();
        $("#default").hide();
         
    } 
    
    // unhide
    elem.show();
    
}

function setDefault(elem){
    $("#default").show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Checkbox -->
<input type="checkbox" id="i" name="cc" value="i_div_id" data-ref="i_div_id" />
<label>I</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="c" name="cc" value="c_div_id" data-ref="c_div_id" />
<label>C</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="p" name="cc" value="p_div_id" data-ref="p_div_id" />
<label>P</label>
        
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<!-- Loaded/hidden content div-->
<div id="listings">
<div class="hide-me" id="default"><strong>This is default copy on page</strong></div>
<div class="hide-me" id="i_div_id" style="display:none;">You ordered: <strong>I Package</strong></div>
<div class="hide-me" id="c_div_id" style="display:none;">You ordered: <strong>C Package</strong></div>
<div class="hide-me" id="p_div_id" style="display:none;">You ordered: <strong>P Package</strong></div>
<div class="hide-me" id="ic_div_id" style="display:none;">You ordered: <strong>I-C Package</strong></div>
<div class="hide-me" id="ip_div_id" style="display:none;">You ordered: <strong>I-P Package</strong></div>
<div class="hide-me" id="cp_div_id" style="display:none;">You ordered: <strong>C-P Package</strong></div>
<div class="hide-me" id="icp_div_id" style="display:none;">You ordered: <strong>I-C-P Package</strong></div>
</div>
```